# Cleaner way to serialize multiple variables in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a cleaner, shorter way of serializing multiple private variables in Unity? Maybe instead of

```
[SerializeField]
private float num1;

[SerializeField]
private float num2;

[SerializeField]
private float num3;

[SerializeField]
private float num4;
```

it could be something like this

```
[SerializeField]
private float num1;
private float num2;
private float num3;
private float num4;
[/SerializeField]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is, and is

```
[SerializeField]
float num1,num2,num3,num4,num5;
[SerializeField]
string name, lastName, address, school;
```

Comment: Well, I just learned something new today. I did not know that would work.

Comment: wow, I thought people above 40k where omniscient or something XD

Comment: For readability, if all these variables had default value assignments, would you then have each on a new line tagged with [SerializeField] or would you simply indent all the variables under the variable type, eg, float.